# How often can I activate planeswalker abilities with Teferi's emblem?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This question relies on [Teferi](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389712)'s emblem which says

> You may activate loyalty abilities of planeswalkers you control on any player's turn any time you could cast an instant.

Since I can activate 1 planeswalker ability per planeswalker per turn could I activate [Jace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=435441)'s *+1 draw a card* ability on each player's turn as long as I have the emblem on board?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since I can activite 1 planeswalker ability per planeswalker per turn could I activate Jace's +1 draw a card ability every player's turn as long as I have the emblem on board ?

Yes, you can.

[Teferi, Temporal Archmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Temporal%20Archmage%5d)'s emblem overrides rule 606.3, specifically the emphasized part:

> 606.3. **A player may activate a loyalty ability of a permanent he or she controls any time he or she has priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of his or her turn**, but only if no player has previously activated a loyalty ability of that permanent that turn.

Which means you can activate any loyalty ability of any permanent (usually a planeswalker) you control at any time you could cast an instant, as long as you have not activated a loyalty ability of that permanent that turn.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes you would be able to Activate [Jace, Ingenious Mind-Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%20Ingenious%20Mind-Mage%5d)'s Ability once on each of your and your opponents turns.**

This is covered on [Teferi, Temporal Archmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Temporal%20Archmage%5d)'s Gatherer page in the rulings:

> If you control Teferi’s emblem, the rule that says you can activate a loyalty ability only if none of that permanent’s loyalty abilities have been activated that turn still applies. In other words, you could activate a planeswalker’s loyalty ability once on your turn and once on each of your opponents’ turns.